# In memory read/write cache in Java based on flat file

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, guava

I have a flat file which consists of a list of device identifiers. When my Java/tomcat based application receives a request from a particular device, it decides the business logic based on presence of the device identifier in the file (The device identifier MAY or MAY NOT be there in the file even though the device exists). Also, there are use cases when

1. new identifiers needs to be added to the file
2. identifiers can be removed from the file.

To make the (multi-threaded) application faster, instead of directly accessing the file for every read/write operation, I need to store the content in-memory.

Here are the requirements (summary) :

1. Read the content of the file in memory (cache) during the application start up.
2. Read the content from the cache in a multi-threaded manner. If the content is not there in the cache it should not be there in the file and vice versa (Single point of truth).
3. When there is a new device identity, the cache as well as file needs to updated.
4. When there is a need to delete a device identity, the cache as well as file needs to updated.
5. The application runs in Java.

What are the options available? I initially thought of using gauva cache. But, I am not sure if it supports writing it's content back to the source file or not. 
Even a simple properties file (java.util.properties) should also do. But, not sure if that will be suitable in a highly multi-threaded environment.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: What level of consistency are you after. Is the file allow to lag slightly behind the in-memory cache or are you after a higher level of consistency.

Comment: The file may lag slightly after. The cache may work as single point of truth.

Comment: What should happen if there is an IOException when reading/writing the file.

Comment: During the startup of the application if there is any IOException the application should not come up. When the application is up if there is an IOException, the read/write operation has to be retired.

Comment: Because you mentioned properties, a spring + commons-configuration solution might also do your work. See an tutorial here: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/reloadedable-properties-file-spring-using-apache-commons-configuration/

Comment: @swinkler Let me check.

Comment: Put all your accesses to the file in a single class. Then make that class thread safe with `java.util.concurrent.lock.ReadWriteLock`. The rest is a piece of cake and is entirely up to your choice. Oh yes, the topic is about cache, but you don't need a specific library to do so if you keep it yourself in memory (which is not forbidden according to your requirements). In that case, just make sure that your "cache" is also accessed exclusively by your locked class.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoireI I would prefer to write the new entries to the cache first and then to the file (May be in bulk). That way I will not block the thread(s) (asking to write a new entry) for a longer time. That is true for deletion as well.

Answer (score 4):

Like most caches, Guava's is designed to be used primarily in a read-through manner. The intent is that the authoritative data source is updated and the cache is then invalidated. The cache does not support write-through or write-behind, and adding those capabilities on top may lead to subtle race conditions.

The Java 8 rewrite, [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), supports adding that functionality through [ConcurrentHashMap's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) atomic compute methods. A write-through uses a `compute` that updates the data source and, if successful, stores the value in the cache. A write-behind uses a `compute` method that asynchronously updates the data source and optimistically stores the value in the cache. In both cases, if the entry exists during a compute then the read is non-blocking and receives the old value until the update completes.

Neither write-through nor write-behind are good approaches for common usages of an in-memory caches. When appropriate they require more thoughtful care and customization, so supplying generic support was thought to lead developers astray and provide little benefit. The rewrite provided the opportunity to make the functionality possible, without promoting it directly.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point using the HashSet as an extension point.

```
 class DeviceCache extends HashSet<Device> {

  boolean add(Device d) {
    boolean rv = super.add(d);

    if (!rv) {
      ... Add the device to the file.
    }

    return rv;
  }

  remove(Device d) {
    boolean rv = super.remove(d);

    if (rv) {
    ... Remove the device from the file
    }

    return fv;
  }
}
```

It is far from complete. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, this can be done. But, writing custom code means I have to take care of multi-threaded access to the cache as well as file which I wanted to avoid. :-(

Comment: Wrap the set in `Collections.synchronizedSet(Set<T> s)`

Comment: Thanks! I can also use Collections.newSetFromMap() backed up by a ConcurrentHashMap.